# Notification From name & From Email

Tags: cognito-forms

Is there a way to configure the from name and from email in Cognito Forms?

I am only given an option between Cognito and user email.

No way to edit the from name or enter a from email.

Answer (score 0):

I'm a developer with [Cognito Forms](https://www.cognitoforms.com).

You can set a default to either be Cognito Forms address that cant be replayed to, or set it to the Email address of the user who is filling out your form. This will give you the ability to reply to the email notification, and have it sent to that user. You can learn more about this in our [Help Content](http://help.cognitoforms.com/notification-emails).

Comment: This is not the case always.

Most of the time, we want our branded email going out, and do not want to carry cognito forms. also, there is a high risk of emails going to spam, when the user email address is in from field. We have tried that in the past with Gravity forms.

Now, with the branded and standard email, our staff will whitelist the email.

I think, it should be a simple and basic requirement for a company that provides "online form service"